# Составление вариативного типа данных в xe7

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7, record

Всем привет! Можно ли в Delphi XE7 (подчеркну в новом, а не в старом. Потому что там много новых директив, новшеств и прочих штучек появилось ;) ) сделать что-то подобное этому?

```
type
      TListComponents = record
         TypeElement: record case Integer of
         0: (ComponentList: TComboBox);
         1: (ComponentList: TListBox);
         2: (ComponentList: TBDComboBox);
         end;
```

Написан неправильный вариант. Смотрел просто вариант записи с case вариативной частью, типа такой:

```
TPerson = record
   FirstName, LastName: string[40];
   BirthDate: TDate;
   case Citizen: Boolean of
     True: (Birthplace: string[40]);
     False: (Country: string[20];
             EntryPort: string[20];
             EntryDate, ExitDate: TDate);
   end;
```

Единственное, что отличает мою задачу от примера с TPerson, что мне надо получить значение разного типа в зависимости от того какое значение TypeElement присвоено. Будет только ComponentList, помимо этого плодить ComponentList2, ComponentList3 не нужно с разными типами данных. Это вообще возможно? Или нужно искать какие-то обходные пути (плюс компактность решения)?

Comment: `TObjectList<TComponent>` не?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оператор `case` в паскалевых (и не только) записях служит одной-единственной цели: экономии пространства стека. Для реализации вашей задачи вам нужно выделить какой-нибудь базовый класс (или интерфейс), от которого все листбоксы наследуют свои методы, и объявить переменную такого типа, либо коллекцию из элементов такого типа. Сейчас Дельфи нет под рукой, но на ум приходит что-то вроде:

```
type
  IListBox = interface
    property Items: TStrings read;
  end;
  TMyComboBox = class(TComboBox, IListBox)
  end;
  TMyListBox = class(TListBox, IListBox)
  end;
  TMyDBComboBox = class(TDBComboBox, IListBox)
  end;

var
  Boxes: TList<IListBox>;
  I, J: Integer;
begin
  Boxes := TArrayList<IListBox>.Create;
  Boxes.Add(TMyComboBox.Create);
  Boxes.Add(TMyListBox.Create);
  Boxes.Add(TMyDBComboBox.Create);
  {...}
  // чуть попозже:
  for I := 0 to Boxes.Count - 1 do
    for J := 0 to Boxes[I].Items.Count - 1 do
      ShowMessage(Boxes[I].Items[J]);
end.
```

И, скорее всего, объявление собственных классов будет излишне. Классы VCL в достаточной степени полиморфны. Например, TCustomListControl содержит практически весь необходимый функционал для управления этими списками.

Comment: Да плодить классы, думаю, лишнее для данной задачи, тем не менее спасибо за правильное направление). Плюсую Ваш ответ и отмечаю его как верным. Хотел еще спросить, где можно просмотреть полную иерархию классов в Delphi XE в виде схемы или чего-то подобного? Хотелось бы иметь перед глазами общую картину дерева классов.Хотя я может многого хочу). Нужно самому копать все.

Comment: Боюсь, в полном виде она будет чересчур громоздкой. Попробуйте поискать "vcl classes hierarchy tree". А так, если нужно происхождение конкретного класса, всё описано в справке. Да и в интернете по типу класса, как правило, можно найти его описание.